What are the linear combination of slater determinant for three electrons on three different spatial orbitals?
I read the following link : https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Pacific_Union_College/Quantum_Chemistry/08%3A_Multielectron_Atoms/8.06%3A_Antisymmetric_Wavefunctions_can_be_Represented_by_Slater_Determinants.
In this link, the excited states deal with two electrons. At the end of this document, for |1,0> (the triplet state with $m_z=0$) and for |0,0> (the singlet state), a linear combination of Slater determinants is used ("the wavefunctions that represent combinations of spinorbitals and hence combinations of electron configurations (e.g., igure 8.6.2) are combinations of Slater determinants")
After, I tried to apply this to a system of three electrons with each electron on a different spatial orbital ($\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_3 $).
I managed to write wavefunctions for the following cases :

|3/2,3/2> and |3/2,-3/2> using a single slater determinant.

For example, for the |3/2,3/2> case :
$$
| \phi (\mathbf{r}_1, \mathbf{r}_2, \mathbf{r}_3) \rangle = 
\dfrac {1}{\sqrt {6}}
\begin{vmatrix} 
\varphi _{1}(1) \alpha(1) & \varphi _{2}(1) \alpha(1) & \varphi _{3}(1) \alpha(1)
\\ 
\varphi _{1}(2) \alpha(2) & \varphi _{2}(2) \alpha(2) & \varphi _{3}(2) \alpha(2)
\\ 
\varphi _{1}(3) \alpha(3) & \varphi _{2}(3) \alpha(3) & \varphi _{3}(3) \alpha(3)
\end{vmatrix}
$$

|3/2,1/2> and |3/2,-1/2> using a linear combination of three slater determinants.

For example, for the |3/2,1/2> case :
$$
| \phi (\mathbf{r}_1, \mathbf{r}_2, \mathbf{r}_3) \rangle = \\
\dfrac {1}{6} 
\left(
\begin{vmatrix} 
\varphi _{1}(1) \alpha(1) & \varphi _{2}(1) \alpha(1) & \varphi _{3}(1) \beta(1)
\\ 
\varphi _{1}(2) \alpha(2) & \varphi _{2}(2) \alpha(2) & \varphi _{3}(2) \beta(2)
\\ 
\varphi _{1}(3) \alpha(3) & \varphi _{2}(3) \alpha(3) & \varphi _{3}(3) \beta(3)
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix} 
\varphi _{1}(1) \alpha(1) & \varphi _{2}(1) \beta(1) & \varphi _{3}(1) \alpha(1)
\\ 
\varphi _{1}(2) \alpha(2) & \varphi _{2}(2) \beta(2) & \varphi _{3}(2) \alpha(2)
\\ 
\varphi _{1}(3) \alpha(3) & \varphi _{2}(3) \beta(3) & \varphi _{3}(3) \alpha(3)
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix} 
\varphi _{1}(1) \beta(1) & \varphi _{2}(1) \alpha(1) & \varphi _{3}(1) \alpha(1)
\\ 
\varphi _{1}(2) \beta(2) & \varphi _{2}(2) \alpha(2) & \varphi _{3}(2) \alpha(2)
\\ 
\varphi _{1}(3) \beta(3) & \varphi _{2}(3) \alpha(3) & \varphi _{3}(3) \alpha(3)
\end{vmatrix}
\right)
$$
That gives :
$$
=
\dfrac {1}6 
\underbrace{[ 
\varphi_{1}(1) \varphi_{2}(2) \varphi_{3}(3) - \varphi_{1}(2) \varphi_{2}(1) \varphi_{3}(3)
+
\varphi_{1}(2) \varphi_{2}(3) \varphi_{3}(1) - \varphi_{1}(3) \varphi_{2}(2) \varphi_{3}(1)
+
\varphi_{1}(3) \varphi_{2}(1) \varphi_{3}(2) - \varphi_{1}(1) \varphi_{2}(3) \varphi_{3}(2)
]}
_{\text{spatial component}}
\underbrace{[ 
\alpha(1)\alpha(2)\beta(3)+
\alpha(1)\beta(2)\alpha(3)+
\beta(1)\alpha(2)\alpha(3)]}
_{\text{spin component}}
$$
So, the spin and the spatial parts are separated and the electrons are indistinguishable.
But , I am not able to find similar wave functions for the four remaining cases : |1/2,1/2>$_1$, |1/2,-1/2>$_1$, |1/2,1/2>$_2$, |1/2,-1/2>$_2$
Is there a solution or not ?
Thanks for answer.
